# Invoke a cleanup method for java user thread, when JVM stops the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have J2SE application running in linux. I have stop application script in which i am doing kill of the J2SE pid. This J2SE application has 6 infinitely running user threads,which will be polling for some specific records in backend DB.

When this java pid is killed, I need to perform some cleanup operations for each of the long running thread, like connecting to DB and set status of some transactions which are in-progress to empty.

Is there a way to write a method in each of the thread, which will be called when the thread is going to be stopped, by JVM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always try to implement a shut down hook using [`Runtime.addShutDownHook`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), or encapsulate the long-running-code in a `try` and the cleanup in `finally`.

A minimal example doing roughly what you want to do (but for a single worker thread for simplicity).

```
public class Test extends Thread {

    static volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Thread t = new Test();
        t.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
                keepRunning = false;
                t.interrupt();
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning) {
            System.out.println("worknig...");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        System.out.println("cleaning up.");
    }
}
```

---

Output when interrupting with Ctrl-C:

```
worknig...
worknig...
worknig...
^CShutting down...
cleaning up.
```

---

Output when killing with `kill pid`

```
worknig...
worknig...
worknig...
worknig...
Shutting down...
cleaning up.
```

---

Output when killing with `kill -9 pid`

```
worknig...
worknig...
worknig...
worknig...
worknig...
Killed
```

(No cleanup executed.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The java process runs in red hat linux OS.
And in my stopApplication script, I am getting the PID of the java process (stored in a file, when starting up), and doing kill -15 (SIGTERM), sleeping for 40 sec, and then doing kill -9 of the pid.

Just want to know, when kill -15 pid is executed, will the Runtime.addshutdownHook be invoked ?

Comment: Yep. `kill -15 PID` yields the same output of the java program as the output of `kill PID` (See above.)